# Creating a single instance of an object for composition vs SomeClass().someMethod() performance

Tags: python, performance, oop

I am not sure if the title is descriptive of my question really but I don't know how to better phrase it. I am working with an API that has a Util class for gui testing. Inside the Util class there are a lot of functions such as click, type, and other gui interactions. I am wondering what the benefits and downsides are creating an instance of Util inside my class vs calling Util() directly.

Example:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.util = Util()
        #The rest of the init code
    def typeSomething(self, text):
        self.util.type(text)
```

vs

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #The rest of the init code
    def typeSomething(self, text):
        Util().type(text)
```

This question is mainly just out of curiosity and to learn as I am assuming there won't be a human noticeable impact either way. Thank you in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, performance-wise it may e irrelevant. So irrelevant, in fact that it may be difficult to even say which method would be faster. However, if you know that constructing `Util()` is expensive and you expect to call `typeSomething(...)` often, then the instance of util becomes a resource and should be a member.